# tmux not loading asdf config

Tags: tmux, oh-my-zsh, asdf-vm

I'm having trouble loading the correct version of ruby/node when I create a tmux session. This doesn't happen if I use ruby/node without tmux

```
$ tmux new-session -s servers
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Compared to normal terminal session:

```
/Users/amree/.asdf/shims/ruby
```

Related dotfiles:

- https://github.com/amree/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf
- https://github.com/amree/dotfiles/blob/master/zshrc

More information

- It's running the same shell (with and without `tmux`). I confirmed it by running `echo $SHELL`
- Commenting out the whole `tmux` config file doesn't help

Comment: Is `tmux` loading up `bash` or `zsh`? Is there a different shell being loaded when you open the terminal vs tmux?

Comment: Also what happens if you load up `tmux` without any config (by moving the tmux.conf and associated files) out of the tmux load path?

Comment: `tmux` is loading `zsh`. Confirmed by running `echo $SHELL` and based on its look. This is the same shell that run without `tmux`

Comment: @alpha_989 I commented out everything in `.tmux.conf` and it's still loading `zsh` and the problem still persists (not loading the correct ruby or node version correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem was because of the `$PATH` has been prepended automatically by `/etc/zprofile` again when I opened the tmux session.

In order to prevent that, I just disable it when it's in tmux session:

```
# /etc/zprofile
# system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
  if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Mac 13.2+ doesn't seem to allow editing /etc/zprofile as it is read-only protected, is there another way to solve this?